# Setting TOC depth in beamer_presentation with RMarkdown

Tags: beamer, presentations, markdown

How can we set the number of Table of Contents levels (depth) that is displayed  in RMarkdown `beamer_presentation`? For HTML documents, I have [found](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html) that a `toc_depth` option exists, but it doesn't seem to be recognized with the `beamer_presentation` output format.

Comment: What shall the toc do? only display sections?

Comment: @samcarter I have `slide_level` set to 3 (###) so I want levels 1 (#) and 2 (##) displayed in the TOC.

Comment: Maybe something like `\tableofcontents[subsubsectionstyle=hide/hide/hide]`?

Comment: @samcarter It is perhaps not the most elegant solution (I thought it's possible with a header option - as it is possible for HTML documents!), but it works, so thank you! If you rephrase it as an answer, I happily accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show only sections and subsection in the toc, but not subsubsections, set the subsubsection style to `hide`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[subsubsectionstyle=hide]
\end{frame}

\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\subsubsection{title}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: This essentially solves the question, but pertains to generic beamer and not to RMarkdown (with beamer_presentation as output format), as in the question. Perhaps it'd be more elegant if you'd rephrase the MWE to match the question, before I accept it.

Comment: @TamasFerenci Sorry, but I have no idea how RMarkdown works - so I can only offer a beamer solution.

Comment: Just for the record then: `\tableofcontents[subsubsectionstyle=hide/hide/hide]` should be included (in the body of the RMarkdown file). Thanks!